# Google Script - Create HtmlOutput from string only? (ie. Convert string to html)

Tags: javascript, html, string, google-apps-script

I have a string that is faux-html. ie:

```
var myHtml = "<div style=\"background:color:#000\">This is text</div>";
```

(Obviously its much longer and more complex than that, but it's a string nonetheless).

In apps script I need to send that to an API as actual HTML. so I want to convert the string to an actual Html Object.

I can make an actual Html file in the sidebar and reference that with 'CreateHtmlOutputfromFile(file)', but would prefer to **not** have to actually make the blank html file.

Is there any way of making a floating html file? Something to the effect of:

```
var myHtml = "<div style=\"background:color:#000\">This is text</div>";
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.CreateHtmlOutput();
htmlOutput.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`createHtmlOutput(String)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutput(String)) method:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(myHtml);
```